# php quick form creation

Tags: php, forms

I have been using php from some time and I have noticed that it takes a long time to create a form with validation using php. Are there any scripts or IDE wizards which can assist a programmer to create php forms quickly and also give the programmer flexibility to customize the form easily?
I found some webservices which provide such services but they are mostly oriented towards non-programmers and the forms they generate are not easily customizable and do not support all kinds of functionalities. Infact, most of them are meant for generating contact forms.

Regards,
Akshey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many code libraries, such as [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html) or [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html), are built to handle this sort of thing. Are you using any library at the moment, or coding by hand?

Looking at PEAR for a moment, I also see that they have a [QuickForm](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2) module.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not using any library or framework. I am coding by hand. I think QuickForm module will help.

Answer (score 3):

I have found symfony framework very useful. Checck the starting tutorial here http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/ You can fnd libraries for many common tasks.